# Electron: Sending Message from a webview to the host on runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

is it possible to send messages between the webview and the renderer that contains the webview?

My idea is to have buttons on the webview and on click it should send a message to the renderer.

I dont know how to do it but it worked when i use a preload file and send a message on webview load but not on the runtime of the webview.

Code that worked in preload

```
// preload.js
ipcRenderer.sendToHost('ipc-message', 'test message');

// renderer.js
tab.webview.addEventListener('ipc-message', (event) => {
    console.log(event)
})
```

Code that is not working

```
// preload.js
$('.tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ipcRenderer.sendToHost('ipc-message', 'test message') 
})

// renderer.js
tab.webview.addEventListener('ipc-message', (event) => {
    console.log(event)
})
```

## **EDIT**

I found a solution.

i did not require jQuery inside the preload.js and i forgot to add "window.onload"

That Code worked:

```
// preload.js
window.onload = function() {
   const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
    
    const $ = require('jquery');
    $('.tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ipcRenderer.sendToHost('ipc-message', 'test message') 
    })
};
```

Comment: I think it would help if you showed the code you used to make this work in the preload.

Comment: i did it, thank you for the hint